# Is there a Win32 Disk Imager equivalent, or an easy way to create .IMG files with a GUI on Mac OS X?

Tags: sd-card, macos

.IMG files seem to be a very good way to backup and restore Raspberry Pi SD Cards, but as far as I can tell there seems to be no equivalent on the Mac.

Maybe?!

PS. Please don't tell me to use the "dd" command, I'd love for the app to have a GUI.

Comment: You say "maybe a terminal command?" then tell us not to give you a command.

Comment: Edited... yes well... there are those terminal apps that sport some kind of primitive GUI. "dd" is so much more than a terminal command, it's a "blind" terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Yes!*** I've found a solution. All thanks to the popularity of the Raspberry I might add. On http://kano.me they make some kind of mini computer Raspberry Pi kit for kids and on one of their **guides** they do this. **Click here and follow the guide:** https://help.kano.me/hc/en-us/articles/201602232-How-to-Re-install-Kano-OS-Using-ApplePi-Baker-OS-X-

The utility is called **ApplePi-Baker** and it's available here: http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Flashing_the_SD_card_using_Mac_OSX
and here:
http://www.tweaking4all.com/hardware/raspberry-pi/macosx-apple-pi-baker/

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you didn't want to use `dd` but you may find this useful.

All you have to do is insert the SD Card and run the following. I does all the difficult stuff.

You may have to modify `/temp/Pi/` to match the desired location for the image.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to backup Pi SD card
# 2014-07-20
#DSK='disk4'
# Find disk with LInux partition (works for Raspbian)
export DSK=`diskutil list | grep "Linux" | cut -c 69-73`
if [ $DSK ]; then
    echo $DSK
else
    echo "Disk not found"
    exit
fi
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/$DSK
echo pleae wait - This takes some time
echo Ctl+T to show progress!
time sudo dd of=~/temp/Pi/Piback.img if=/dev/r$DSK bs=2m
echo backup completed - now compressing
time gzip -9 ~/temp/Pi/Piback.img
#rename to current date
echo compressing completed - now renaming
mv -n ~/temp/Pi/Piback.img.gz ~/temp/Pi/Piback`date +%Y%m%d`.img.gz
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to compose an answer. I'll wait a while maybe something else pops up.

Comment: managed to find a way around this see: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28604/27866